# Getting Registration Tokens GCM vs FCM

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am reading the documentation on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) under the heading "Retrieve the current registration token."  I am confused by what it says.

The initial paragraph is very simple.  It says we simply have to call...

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken
```

That sounds very easy until I read the next paragraph that says I need to implement MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java...

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService
{

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
}
```

So the first paragraph seems to say can make the call anyplace when I want to but the second paragraph has me wraping the call inside an onTokenRefresh().

So this begs the question WHEN does onTokenRefresh get called?  With GCM I was able to choose WHEN I made the call asking for the token.  With FCM it appears that we wait for onTokenRefresh to be called somewhere in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the same linked document:

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

It is strongly recommended that `onTokenRefresh()` is handled since there is a (rare) possibility that calling `getToken()` would (from the same docs):

> This method returns null if the token has not yet been generated.

I think my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50092786/4625829) has a bit more explanation.

With all that said, calling `getToken()` would (most of the time) give you a token immediately, but in a case that it doesn't, `onTokenRefresh()` is there.

Answer (score 0):

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579912/6143482)

> The onTokenRefresh() method is going to be called whenever a new token
>   is generated. Upon app install, it will be generated immediately (as
>   you have found to be the case). It will also be called when the token
>   has changed.

Just like an `onEdit()` function is called when an edit is made or `onOpen()` is called when the app is opened.